# JQuery TOOLS overlay in Safari comes up aligned to left side of page instead of middle of page

Tags: jquery, css, safari, overlay, jquery-tools

New website at : removed for privacy

In Safari, on the homepage, click the Share link.

The overlay comes up aligned to the left side of the page instead of centered.

If I close the overlay and reopen it, it's centered.

Any ideas how to get it centered on first click?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be unique to my scenario, but I was able to fix this problem by setting the modal container CSS-Display attribute to "none" and oddly enough, it worked on refresh.